# Replacing selected text in Emacs with one character

Tags: replace

In Vim, I can do this trick on a line with the words "People":

yy p Shift-v r +

It will produce a set of lines that like this:

People

++++++

I would like to be able to reproduce this in Emacs if possible.

Comment: Many/most people on this site will not understand the Vim commands you cite.  Please explain what they do.

Comment: You might try `evil-mode`: https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil

Comment: yy is copy a line, p is paste it below, shift-v is select the pasted line, r is replace the selected text with +

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use <kbd>C-M-%</kbd> (`query-replace-regexp`) to replace the pattern `.` with `+` in the region (In Emacs regexp, `.` matches any characters except newline).